# Chart.js - Formatting Y axis

Tags: string-formatting, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to draw a simple bar plot and I need to format its Y axis like

> 123456.05 to 123 456,05 $

I don't understand how to use [`scaleLabel : "<%=value%>"`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)

I saw [someone pointing](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/68#issuecomment-20487489) to "[JS Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)",
but no clue how to use that with our `scaleLabel` option.

Does someone know how to format this Y axis, and maybe give me an example ?

Comment: OP: Please re-consider chosen answer

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I had the same problem, I think in **Chart.js 2.x.x** the approach is slightly different like below.

```
ticks: {
    callback: function(label, index, labels) {
        return label/1000+'k';
    }
}
```

More in details

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                        return label/1000+'k';
                    }
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: '1k = 1000'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: it's nice to hear that.

Comment: This also seems to be the right way to do with angular-chart.js

Comment: this Ans must be accepted . i think this will work on new versions likely on 2.x.x and above. i have a new version and i tried many other solutions found in the web ,but nothing worked . this is the only thing worked for me ..

Comment: This works well. This should be accepted as the answer.

Took me an hour to find this. Why this is not in the documentation, is beyond me.

How did you find this, Jaison?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, helped me a lot with my project.

Comment: That's it ! ! ! !

Comment: If I have a method somewhere that adds K, M, B to numbers like 1000 => 1k. I tried calling the function inside the callback: function but it doesn't seem to work, why? and how can I call my method inside the callback?

Comment: Can any one have solution for displaying mixed font style for labels ?
stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731460/chart-js-customizing-tick-labels-for-mixed-font-styles
codepen:  https://codepen.io/faltherr/pen/jONLVjd?editors=1011

Comment: Have anyway to do the same thing without callback function? If answer is NO please tell me why?

Answer (score 58):

An undocumented feature of the ChartJS library is that if you pass in a function instead of a string, it will use your function to render the y-axis's scaleLabel.

So while, `"<%= Number(value).toFixed(2).replace('.',',') + ' $' %>"` works, you could also do:

```js
scaleLabel: function (valuePayload) {
    return Number(valuePayload.value).toFixed(2).replace('.',',') + '$';
}
```

If you're doing anything remotely complicated, I'd recommend doing this instead.

Comment: That's actual the best answer here. Due to a simple IF the function is directly called instead of running the embedded template parser which calls the JS code indirectly.

Comment: where goes scaleLabel?

Answer (score 15):

```js
scaleLabel : "<%= Number(value).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + ' $'%>"
```

Comment: why its not working for me. Please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256476/how-to-change-the-y-axis-to-show-in-chartjs

Answer (score 15):

For anyone using `3.X.X`, here's the updated syntax to change y axis labels:

```
scales: {
  y: {
    ticks: {
      callback: (label) => `$ ${label}`,
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Andersen.
I wanted to transform yAxes from: `1 - 2 - 3` etc..
to `1.0 - 2.0 - 3.0` and it was as simple as:
`callback: (label) => '${label}.0',`

Comment: I had to define the callback like this: `callback: function (value) {return \`$ ${this.getLabelForValue(value)}\`}` to make this work. I found the `getLabelForValue` method in the docs here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html

Answer (score 12):

**Chart.js 2.X.X**

I know this post is old. But if anyone is looking for more flexible solution, here it is

```js
var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                    return Intl.NumberFormat().format(label);
                    // 1,350
                    return Intl.NumberFormat('hi', { 
                        style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', minimumFractionDigits: 0, 
                    }).format(label).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ');
                    // ₹ 1,350
                    // return Intl.NumberFormat('hi', {
                        style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', currencyDisplay: 'symbol', minimumFractionDigits: 2 
                    }).format(label).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ');
                    // ₹ 1,350.00
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

'hi' is Hindi. Check here for other **locales argument**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation#locales_argument

for more **currency symbol**
https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

Comment: Worked like charm! ty!

Answer (score 5):

As Nevercom said the scaleLable should contain javascript so to manipulate the y value just apply the required formatting.

Note the the value is a string.

```js
var options = {      
    scaleLabel : "<%= value + ' + two = ' + (Number(value) + 2)   %>"
};
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vy0yhd6m/)

if you wish to set a manual y scale you can use scaleOverride

```js
var options = {      
    scaleLabel : "<%= value + ' + two = ' + (Number(value) + 2)   %>",

    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 10,
    scaleStepWidth: 10,
    scaleStartValue: 0

};
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vy0yhd6m/1/)

Comment: very clear, i was confused how to use scaleLabel with custom values Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/68#issuecomment-20918194) you can find a good example of how to format Y-Axis value.

Also, you can use `scaleLabel : "<%=value%>"` that you mentioned, It basically means that everything between `<%=` and `%>` tags will be treated as javascript code (i.e you can use `if` statments...)

Answer (score 1):

with chartjs 4.4.0,
i found the way to change the number format alone,
without need to change the labels or tooltip layouts or callbacks.
this is the way i implemented the example of @Dexter above.

```
const options = {
...
    locale: 'hi',
    ticks: {
        format: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'INR',
            currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2, 
        },
    },
...
};
```