# Charts.js Formatting Y Axis with both Currency and Thousands Separator

Tags: javascript, function, chart.js

I'm using Charts.js to show a graph on my site. Currently, the label shows as a long string of numbers (i.e 123456).
I want it to show as currency with thousands separator: (i.e $123,456)

I'm using the scaleLabel option to put a $ USD symbol before the value:

```
scaleLabel: "<%= ' $' + Number(value)%>"
```

and a function to insert the comma separator:

```
function(label){return label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}
```

I just do not know how to use these together to get what I want.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vy0yhd6m/79/

*(please keep in mind that currently the graph will only work if you remove one of those two pieces of JavaScript cited above)*

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38299304/1374554

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should be able to include currency prefix in composition of label inside function...

```
var options = {
    animation: false,
    scaleLabel:
    function(label){return  '$' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy0yhd6m/80/

Comment: Thank you it worked! I will accept your answer in 7 minutes when the websites allows me to :-)

Comment: This is only for 1.x of Chart.js, scroll down if you need an answer for 2.x or greater.

Comment: this does not work for a "complex" scaleLabel containing multiple values, you need { something1: something1, something2: something2, callback: function(label) etc. etc.}

Answer (score 119):

I'm new to chart.js, but here's what I had to do to make Billy Moon's answer work with the latest version 2.1.6.

```
  var data = {
    labels: ["12 AM", "1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "4 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Sales $",
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(143,199,232,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(108,108,108,1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#535353",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      }
    ]
  };

  //var myChart =
  new Chart(document.getElementById('sales-summary-today'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
      animation: false,
      legend: {display: false},
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              if(parseInt(value) >= 1000){
                return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              } else {
                return '$' + value;
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

Again, credit goes to Billy Moon's Answer for the label formatting function.

Comment: This is the solution for charts v2. The other solutions listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371867/chart-js-formatting-y-axis/28700578#28700578 don't seem to work on the latest release

Comment: thanks! We can also use `toLocaleString` instead of all the regex and conditionals, just simply:
`return "$" + parseInt(value).toLocaleString();`

Answer (score 50):

I'm mostly summarizing what others have mentioned, but I think the cleanest solution to this exact (and frequently encountered) question is to utilize [the `toLocaleString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) with USD currency formatting:

```
return value.toLocaleString("en-US",{style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
```

This works in all modern browsers. The [Mozilla documentation for `toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Syntax) lists specific browser compatibility and options for other locales, currencies, and formatting types (e.g. percentages).

Note Chart.js Version 2+ (released in April 2016) [requires using the `callback` method](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-creating-custom-tick-formats) for advanced tick formatting:

```
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
     scales: {
       yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
           callback: function(value, index, values) {
             return value.toLocaleString("en-US",{style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
           }
         }
       }]
     }
   }
 });
```

The syntax if you are using [Chart.js Version 1.X](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/v1.1.1/docs) would be:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
var data = {
  ...
}
var options = {
  scaleLabel: function(label) {
    return value.toLocaleString("en-US",{style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
}
```

Credit to Perry Tew for [referencing the syntax change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38005962/1054570), and to mfink for [the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523394/charts-js-formatting-y-axis-with-both-currency-and-thousands-separator#comment63816320_38005962) to use `toLocaleString`.

Comment: why would you think this wouldnt work for tooltips ?  tried putting this in my tooltip callback, nothing

Comment: For those who want to remove the decimal points from the currency: `{style:"currency", currency:"USD",minimumFractionDigits:0,maximumFractionDigits:0}`

Comment: What if the symbol can change? How can you pass it, and the placement (before/after) the number?

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Perry Tew's answer, if you have negative dollar amounts on your axes (e.g. when displaying a profit/loss chart), you can use this:

```
ticks: {
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
        if(parseInt(value) > 999){
            return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        } else if (parseInt(value) < -999) {
            return '-$' + Math.abs(value).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        } else {
            return '$' + value;
        }
    }
}
```

The correct format for displaying negative currencies is -$XXX, so we prepend `-$` to the value, and then run it through Math.abs(), which converts it to positive.

Answer (score 8):

In chartjs v2.0, you can set a global options like this:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label = function(tooltipItem, data) {
    return tooltipItem.yLabel.toLocaleString("en-US");
};

Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('linear', {
    ticks: {
        callback: function (value, index, values) {
            return value.toLocaleString();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Charts.js for Angular 2+ (ng2-charts) you can use `CurrencyPipe`. Here is how I formatted the label:

Inject the dependency within your page.ts file:

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Here is how I call it within my chart options:

```
public chartOptions: any = {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false,
            labels: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'single',
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              let label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
              let datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
              let currencyPipe = new CurrencyPipe('en');
              let formattedNumber = currencyPipe.transform(datasetLabel, 'USD', 'symbol');
              return label + ': ' + formattedNumber;
            }
          }
        }
    };
```

**UPDATE 2022-04-07:** The syntax has changed for Chart.js version 3. Here is what the options object looks like if you are using v3:

```
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartData, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

public chart_options: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
   layout: {
      padding: 25,
   },
   responsive: true,
   plugins: {
      legend: {
         display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
         enabled: true,
         callbacks: {
            label: function(context) {
               let currency_pipe = new CurrencyPipe('en');
               return ' ' + context.label + ': ' + currency_pipe.transform(context.parsed, 'USD', 'symbol');
            }
         }
      }
   }
};

public chart_type: ChartType = 'doughnut';
public chart_labels: string[] = [];
public chart_data: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {
   labels: this.chart_labels,
   datasets: [{
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: [],
   }]
};

<div style="display: block;">
   <canvas baseChart [data]="chart_data" [options]="chart_options" [type]="chart_type"></canvas>
</div>
```

[Check out the Chart.js v3 Migration Guide for more info](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Answer (score 5):

Using chartjs v2.8.0, after looking around the docs, I found it [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats).

Instead of making my own formatter, I'm using [numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/#format) to format the number.
So this is what I do:

`import numeral from 'numeral'`

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value, index, values) {
          // add comma as thousand separator
          return numeral(value).format('0,0')
        },
      }
    }]
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || ''

        if (label) {
          label += ': '
        }
        label += numeral(tooltipItem.yLabel).format('0,0')
        return label
      },
    },
  },
}
```

You can use `format('$ 0,0')` to add currency symbol along with comma thousand separator.

Answer (score 4):

I know my answer is too late but due to op are getting more attention this may relevant now.

Here is the more simple and decent approach.

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
}); // Change locale according to your currency and country

var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
                ticks: {
                    callback: (label, index, labels) => {
                        return formatter.format(label);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here by Perry Tew, AJ A. *et al* yield a

`Invalid scale configuration for scale: yAxes`

error for me. I'm guessing that's because of a change in version 3.

Per the [current docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html) this slight change seems to work:

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                    return value.toLocaleString("en-CA", {
                        style: "currency", 
                        currency: "CAD", 
                        minimumFractionDigits:0, 
                        maximumFractionDigits:0});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a specific javascript function to convert a long number into a number formatted according to system settings: toLocaleString().

You can specify that the label of each tick (or of a specific tick identified by its number index) must be built by your own function, by adding "callback:" keyword inside tick options:

Before:

```
        ticks: {
                  max: maxAltitude,
                  min: 0
                }
```

After:

```
        ticks: {
                  max: maxAltitude,
                  min: 0, // <--- dont' foget to add this comma if you already have specified ticks options
                    callback:  
                      function(value, index, valuesArray) {
                          // value: currently processed tick label
                          // index of currently processed tick label
                          // valuesArray: array containing all predefined labels
                          return  value.toLocaleString(); 
                      } // Function end
                } // Ticks options end
```

Without the comments and without unused variables:

```
        ticks: {
                  max: maxAltitude,
                  min: 0, 
                  callback:  
                      function(value) {
                        return  value.toLocaleString(); 
                      }
                }
```