# Add information on y Chart Js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On my y axis I have value from 0 to n.
I need to display this number in this style:
2 (s)
1 (s)

I just want to add "(s)" but if I do this :

```
data: latency+"(s)"
```

It doesn't work.
Latency is the array where I have numbers.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart.js - Formatting Y axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371867/chart-js-formatting-y-axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the option

```
scaleLabel: "<%=value%> (s)",
```

if you want to change the display on the scale.

Or, if you want to change the display in the tooltip, set `tooltipTemplate` or `multiTooltipTemplate` depending on whether you have a single or multiple series.

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %> (s)",
```

or

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value %> (s)",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `scaleLabel`   option like this :

```
scaleLabel : "<%=value%>(s)"
```

For example, you can set it in the global Chart options :

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
    scaleLabel : "<%=value%>(s)"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `scaleLabel` property.

Look at this:
[Chart.js - Formatting Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371867/chart-js-formatting-y-axis)

try :

```
scaleLabel: function (valuePayload) {
    return valuePayload.value + '$';
}
```