# Laravel 5.1 format date array for chart.js data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, chart.js

Apologies, I can't upload my controller code right now but I'm hoping you can help with the info I can give you.

I'm using `chart.js` to plot a line graph of data. I'm passing the values from my controller for the data points and the date that matches the date point. The date labels are on the `x` axis and the data points are on the `y` axis.

In my view I'm receiving the following array from the controller:

```
["2015-06-01","2015-05-01","2015-04-01","2015-03-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01"]
```

Which is then being encoded into JSON. Now, should I be attempting to format the date into something a bit more readable inside the controller or inside the view?

**EDIT**

This is my piece of code that's sending my weight data to my view:

`$weight = Weight::where(compact('user_id', 'gecko_id'))->orderBy('weighed_date', 'desc')->take(7)->get()->reverse();`

and then

```
return view('gecko.show')
            ->with('gecko', $gecko)
            ->with('dates', $weight->lists('weighed_date'))
            ->with('amounts', $weight->lists('gecko_weight'));
```

Comment: As far as I know the view is responsible for only displaying the data. So, you should format the date on your controller. Alternatively, you can use query scope on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I managed to achieve this was formatting the date inside my controller before sending it to my view. I will post code later when I'm not at work :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say format it in `ChartJS` itself if your purely looking to change it as part of the presentation. If you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371867/chart-js-formatting-y-axis) we see that we can format our labels for data points using something like.

```
scaleLabel: function (valuePayload) {
    return Number(valuePayload.value).toFixed(2).replace('.',',') + '$';
}
```

now in your case you could maybe do something like

```
scaleLabel: function (value) {
    return moment(value).format("ddd, hA"); ;
}
```

to format date in a nice way. Making use of [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) in this case.

Warning: Above is not tested I've never done this with `ChartJS` but in theory it should work.

Comment: Hey mark, thanks for this. I'll give it a go on my lunch break. My `date` labels are across the `x` axis. Will this still work? Looking at the code scaleLabel appears to be the `y` axis, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Ah your right Andy I'll have a look when I have a minute see if I can update it for the `x` axis. I know how to do this with like 5 different charting libraries just never used `ChartJS` so not sure of all its features.

Comment: No problemo :) Thanks for taking a look