# Chart.js does not display any data

Tags: angular, chart.js, linechart

I have a data coming from the server in the following format:

```
[
  {
    name: "series1"
    series: [
    {
        date: "2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        value: 49
      },
      {
        date: "2016-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        value: 49
      },
      {
        date: "2016-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        value: 44
      },
      {
        date: "2016-04-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        value: 57
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    name: "series2"
    series: [
       ...
    ]
  }
]
```

Every point in the series above represent monthly data

Here is my chart declaration:

```
this.ctx = this.myChartRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: this.data[0].name,
            fill: false,
            data: [
              this.data[0].series.map((x) => {
                return {
                  x: this.dateTickFormatting(x.date),
                  y: x.value
                }
              })
            ],
          }, {
            label: this.data[1].name,
            fill: false,
            data: [
              this.data[1].series.map((x) => {
                return {
                  x: this.dateTickFormatting(x.date),
                  y: x.value
                }
              })
            ],
          }]
      },
      options: {
          responsive: true,
          title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'My Chart',
              fontSize: 18
          },
          legend: {
              display: true,
              position: "top"
          },
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  type: 'time',
                  time: {
                      unit: 'month',
                      displayFormats: {
                          'month': 'MMM YYYY',
                      },
                      tooltipFormat: "MMM YYYY"
                  }
              }],
          }
      }
    });
```

function `dateTickFormatting` returns string like that:

```
 return new Date(val).toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });
```

When I am running the code above the cart does not show any values, what I see is only blank canvas with horizontal lines.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your data and in your code:

1. The provided data is not of valid JSON format (lots of commas missing)
2. The `data` option inside individual `datasets` is not correctly created

   - It must not be a nested array but a simple array
   - The `Date` must not be converted to `string` as you currently do using `dateTickFormatting`

> Please also note that `moment.js` needs to be imported if you're not using a bundled build of Chart.js.

The following runnable code snippet illustrates how it can be done.

```js
const data = [{
    name: "series1",
    series: [{
            date: "2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 49
        },
        {
            date: "2016-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 49
        },
        {
            date: "2016-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 44
        },
        {
            date: "2016-04-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 57
        }
    ]
}, {
    name: "series2",
    series: [{
            date: "2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 12
        },
        {
            date: "2016-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 32
        },
        {
            date: "2016-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 28
        },
        {
            date: "2016-04-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            value: 48
        }
    ]
}];

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
          {
              label: data[0].name,
              fill: false,
              backgroundColor: 'red',
              borderColor: 'red',
              data: data[0].series.map(x => ({ x: new Date(x.date), y: x.value }))
          }, {
              label: data[1].name,
              fill: false,
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              data: data[1].series.map(x => ({ x: new Date(x.date), y: x.value }))
          }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'My Chart',
            fontSize: 18
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'month',
                    displayFormats: {
                        'month': 'MMM YYYY',
                    },
                    tooltipFormat: 'MMM YYYY'
                }
            }],
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: right, I just missed the commas in my json array (just fixed that in original question). Why would you need a moment here?

Comment: Because Chart.js internally uses moment.js for formatting date/time values and I'm using stand-alone build in my code sample (see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#selecting-the-correct-build)

Comment: actually it works well without the moment.js ref for me

Comment: Then you probably use a bundled build of Chart.js (see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build)

Comment: btw is there anyway to combine all the tooltips on to one? basically when you hover over the line, right now it is shows tooltip only with the values for the hovered line, but how would you display all the other values for all lines in tooltip if you see what I mean

Comment: I think I've got it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371867/chart-js-formatting-y-axis thanks for your help

Comment: I would rather just add `tooltips: { mode: 'index', intersect: true }` to `options`

Comment: any ideas on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126598/cartjs-tooltips-displays-in-the-wrong-place-on-a-chart ?