# How to disable chartjs tooltip on mibile devices and small screens?

Tags: chart.js

I have to many points on my chart so when I am clicking through on mobile or small screen my tooltip just showing data from multiple points:

[image]

I researched on that and find out the the best approach would be is to disable the tooltip on small screens. I tried to follow [this advice](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html#event-option) from the docs. But have no luck:

```
options: {
        // This chart will not respond to mousemove, etc
        events: ['click']
    }
```

Also I found [that](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/500#issuecomment-50991285) but I think it is actually related to what I just did based on the advice form the docs.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltips can be disabled in the `options` as shown below (see [Tooltip Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration)):

```
option: 
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of using a hard coded value `false`, you may obtain the value from a function that returns `true` or `false` depending on the screen size.

```
option: 
    tooltips: {
        enabled: window.screen.width > 400
    }
    ...
}
```

> I've no experience in creating web apps for mobile devices. Therefore
>   400 is probably not the right choice. The following answer should help
>   finding the appropriate function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/2358409

Comment: how would you stick the function in? is it the one are you talking about https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips? Is there any particular examples?

Comment: Interesting idea `enabled: window.screen.width > 400` do you think `400px width` is the best value to detect if the screen is mobile?

Comment: @sreginogemoh: I've no experience in creating web apps for mobile devices. Therefore 400 is probably not the right choice. The following answer should help finding the appropriate function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/2358409